# Display feature image from wordpress database in my external code

Tags: database, wordpress, image

I have this code and I need to display from database of Wordpress post image. Is there someone, who help me? Now it is showing only title and content of the post from specific author. But I need to display post image...

Thanks

```
$db_username = '***';
$db_password = '***';
$db_database = '***';  

$blog_url = 'myBlogSiteUrl.com/'; //base folder for the blog. Make SURE there is a slash at the end  

//connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect('***', $db_username, $db_password);
@mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Unable to select database");
$query = "
        Select * 
        FROM wp_posts
        WHERE post_type='advert' 
        AND post_author='16' 
        AND post_status='publish' 
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
    ";

$query_result = mysql_query($query);  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_result)) {

    $content = $row['post_content'];

    echo ('
        <div class="blog_cont">
        <strong>'.$row['post_title'].'</strong>
        <br>
        <span>'.$content.'</span>
        <br>
        <a href="'.$row['guid'].'" target="_blank">More >></a>
        ');
}
@mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're making ajax calls, let wordpress handle that for you, then displaying image or anything what is stored in db would be much more easier.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

If not, you can still handle request by Wordpress. In your plugin or template functions.php handle GET request and you can still use wordpress functions.

eg.

```
<?php

isset($_GET['your_custom_get_variable']){

    echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );

    exit(); // don't let wordpress output anything else

}
```

However first method is much more cleaner if only you're making AJAX calls